# Curl request written in C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write a specific curl request in C#, and I keep getting a 500 server error response from the server. This curl request essentially makes a post request to an API by the company Highwinds. This request sends json data, and sets the Auth Bearer token header.

This is the curl request that works fine (note that I've replaced my actual bearer token with {token} and my actual account id with {accountId} to obfuscate that info):

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@data.json" "https://striketracker.highwinds.com/api/accounts/{accountId}/purge"
```

Here's the C# code that gives me a generic 500 server error from the Highwinds API (note that I've replaced my actual bearer token with {token}, my actual account id with {accountId}, and the url in the json string with {url}, in order to obfuscate that personal info):

```
var accountId = "{accountId}";
var purgeURI =  string.Format("https://striketracker.highwinds.com/api/accounts/{0}/purge", {accountId});
var query =
@"{""list"": [{""url"": ""{url}"",""recursive"": true}]}";
var token = {token};


using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{

var url = new Uri(purgeURI);
using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
{
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(),
      string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));

    httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(query,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json");

    await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).ContinueWith(task =>
    {

        var response = task.Result;
        var blah = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    });
}
}
```

Thanks!

*Update: The following line of code was added to remove the Expect header that HttpRequest adds to a request by default. After removing this header I was able to get Highwinds API to accept the request without bombing.

"request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best recommendation would be to proxy both requests through something like *tcpmon* http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/tcpmon/1.0/  (Basically run the server and point to local host and have tcpmon redirect the request to striketracker.highwinds.com).  Try it from curl and from your source and you should be able to see what's different between the requests.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I set up tcpmon as a proxy to listen on port 4000 and for its sender to point this endpoint: "https://striketracker.highwinds.com/api/accounts/{accountid}/purge". I run the web server and tell it to make the request to "http://localhost:4000" however I get an error in tcpmon: "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol". Any help?

Comment: Don't use sender - at least not yet.  Click on "Admin", change "listen port" to something unused on your machine (6005?)  Set "target hostname" to "striketracker.highwinds.com", and target port to "443".   Then try your curl statement again, but replace "striketracker.highwinds.com" with "localhost:6005".  The one problem I think you'll have is that it is probably going to show the data going across encrypted.   If thats the case, hit 80 instead of 443, and if that doesn't work change to port 80 on any known server.

Comment: You're trying to see what is being sent by curl and what is being sent by your app, so the response doesn't matter much as long as there is one.

Comment: So I was finally able to get tcpmon to work correctly based on your advice, and after using tcpmon I was able to compare the requests between curl and what .net sends with the request library. I finally found that Highwinds API, which is where the request was sending to, couldn't handle the "Expect: 100-Continue" header property that HttpRequest adds to a request by default. So after removing that with the following line then it works! 

request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

Comment: WOO HOO!!  That's great to hear!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!